# How to write a test to check that the shadow DOM element is visible?

Tags: javascript

The online store has a drop-down list where the user can select the payment method: credit card, cash, free, leasing. After choosing a payment method, the client goes to the cart, where there is also a drop-down list in which the payment method must match the previously selected one. I need to write a test that randomly selects a payment method and compares the texts inside the elements, but the code has shadow DOM elements and an error appears in cypress

> Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected the subject to host a shadow root, but never found it.

Here is my code:

```
cy.xpath("//div[@class='simple-caption-input form-group--width-fix d--block']//select").shadow().filter(':visible').invoke('text').then((First) => {
cy.xpath('cart').click()
   cy.xpath("//div[@class='simple-caption-input form-group--width-fix d--block']//select").shadow().filter(':visible').invoke('text').then((Second) => {
      expect(First).to.include(Second)
   })
})
```

DevTools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
cy.xpath("//div[@class='simple-caption-input form-group--width-fix d--block']//select").shadowFind('[data-id="' + random_number + '"]').invoke('text').then((First) => {
cy.xpath('cart').click()
   cy.xpath("//div[@class='simple-caption-input form-group--width-fix d--block']//select").shadowFind('[data-id="' + random_number2 + '"]').invoke('text').then((Second) => {
      expect(First).to.include(Second)
   })
})
```